vba powerpoint animation color change
If someone could please help.  I have been fighting this for two days
and I have no idea what to do:
I get this error:
Run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)
AnimationBehavior (unknown member): Invalid request.
On the line:
Print #fileNumber, "Behavior Color Effect: " & behavior.ColorEffect
In the program (script?) (macro):
        x
Sub ListShapeAttributesTestAnim()
    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptShape As shape
    Dim slideIndex As Integer
    Dim paragraph As TextRange
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileNumber As Integer
    Dim vertAlign As String
    Dim horizAlign As String
    Dim effect As effect
    Dim aSlide As slide
    Dim sDisName As String
    Dim sX As String
    Dim Ctr As Integer
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sPictureAdd As String
    Dim iX As Integer
    Dim bX As Boolean
    Dim behavior As AnimationBehavior

    sPath = "C:\MM3\slideInfo\imgs\"
    Ctr = 0

    ' Set the file path
    filePath = "C:\MM3\slideInfo\MySlide.txt"
    fileNumber = FreeFile

    ' Open the file for output
    Open filePath For Output As #fileNumber
   
    slideIndex = pptApp.ActiveWindow.View.slide.slideIndex ' Get the current slide index
    ' Loop through all shapes and their animations on the active slide
    Set aSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(slideIndex)
    Debug.Print "===================================================================="
    ' Loop through all shapes on the active slide
    For Each pptShape In aSlide.Shapes
        Debug.Print "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
        Debug.Print "Shape Name: " & pptShape.Name
        If pptShape.Type <> msoPicture Then
            sX = Trim(pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
            bX = False
            While (bX = False)
                bX = True
                iX = Len(sX)
                If iX > 0 Then
                    If Mid(sX, iX, 1) = vbCrLf Or Mid(sX, iX, 1) = vbCr Or Mid(sX, iX, 1) = vbLf Then
                        If iX > 1 Then
                            sX = Mid(sX, 1, (iX - 1))
                         Else
                            sX = ""
                        End If
                        bX = False
                    End If
                End If
            Wend
            sDisName = ""
            ' Check if the shape has text
            If pptShape.HasTextFrame Then
                Debug.Print "Shape Text: " & sX
                
                ' Loop through each paragraph
                For Each paragraph In pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs
                    sX = Trim(paragraph.Text)
                    sX = Replace(sX, vbCrLf, "", , , vbTextCompare)
                    sX = Replace(sX, vbCr, "", , , vbTextCompare)
                    sX = Replace(sX, vbLf, "", , , vbTextCompare)
                    sDisName = UCase(Trim(sX))
                    Debug.Print "Paragraph: " & sX
                    ' Check for animations in MaiSequence
                    For Each effect In aSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence
                        If effect.shape.Name = pptShape.Name Then
                            sX = Trim(effect.DisplayName)
                            sX = Replace(sX, vbCrLf, "", , , vbTextCompare)
                            sX = Replace(sX, vbCr, "", , , vbTextCompare)
                            sX = Replace(sX, vbLf, "", , , vbTextCompare)
                            sX = UCase(Trim(sX))
                            Debug.Print "Shape Animation Name: " & effect.DisplayName & "[" & sDisName & "] [" & sX & "]"
                            sX = AnimActionSettingsNumber(effect.EffectType)
                            Debug.Print "Shape Animation Type: " & effect.EffectType & " (" & sX & ")"
                            For Each behavior In effect.Behaviors
                                Debug.Print "Behavior Type: " & behavior.Type
                                Print #fileNumber, "Behavior Color Effect: " & behavior.ColorEffect     'ERROR HEARE!!!!!!!!!
                            Next behavior
                        End If  'end of a shape effect
                    Next effect  'end of a (all) effects
                Next paragraph  'end  of a (all) paragraphs
            End If
        End If
    Next pptShape
    ' Close the file
    Close #fileNumber

    MsgBox "Slide attributes written to " & filePath
    
End Sub


I tried to strip out all of the nonessential statements yet leave enough logic so you can see what I am doing.
This is the end of the debug output:
Shape Animation Name:  He has degrees in Mathematics [BUSINESS FOR OVER 30 YEARS.] [HE HAS DEGREES IN MATHEMATICS]
Shape Animation Type: 56 (Font Color Changes)
Behavior Type: 8
Shape Animation Name:      and Computer Science among  [BUSINESS FOR OVER 30 YEARS.] [AND COMPUTER SCIENCE AMONG]
Shape Animation Type: 56 (Font Color Changes)
Behavior Type: 8
Shape Animation Name:      others. [BUSINESS FOR OVER 30 YEARS.] [OTHERS.]
Shape Animation Type: 56 (Font Color Changes)
Behavior Type: 8
Shape Animation Name:  He ran a successful software [BUSINESS FOR OVER 30 YEARS.] [HE RAN A SUCCESSFUL SOFTWARE]
Shape Animation Type: 56 (Font Color Changes)
Behavior Type: 8
Shape Animation Name:       business for over 30 years. [BUSINESS FOR OVER 30 YEARS.] [BUSINESS FOR OVER 30 YEARS.]
Shape Animation Type: 56 (Font Color Changes)
Behavior Type: 8

Shape Name: Picture 2
All I want to do is "trap" the before and after color changes but everything I have tried to do has not worked:
I want to do something like this:
' Check for behaviors related to color change
For Each behavior In effect.Behaviors
Print #fileNumber, "Behavior Type: " & behavior.Type
Print #fileNumber, "Behavior Color Effect: " & behavior.ColorEffect
iX = iX
If behavior.Type = msoAnimTypeColor Then
    Print #fileNumber, "   Color Change Animation Detected"
    With behavior.ColorEffect
        ' Print starting color if defined
        If .From.RGB <> 0 Then
            Print #fileNumber, "   Font Color Change Start: RGB(" & _
                ((.From.RGB And &HFF0000) \ &H10000) & ", " & _
                ((.From.RGB And &HFF00) \ &H100) & ", " & _
                (.From.RGB And &HFF) & ")"
        End If

        ' Print ending color
        If .To.RGB <> 0 Then
            Print #fileNumber, "   Font Color Change End: RGB(" & _
                ((.To.RGB And &HFF0000) \ &H10000) & ", " & _
                ((.To.RGB And &HFF00) \ &H100) & ", " & _
                (.To.RGB And &HFF) & ")"
        End If
    End With
    ' Check if After Animation Effect is set (if applicable)
    Select Case behavior.ColorEffect.AfterEffect
        Case msoAnimAfterEffectNone
            Print #fileNumber, "   After Animation: None"
        Case msoAnimAfterEffectDim
            Print #fileNumber, "   After Animation: Dim to RGB(" & _
                ((behavior.ColorEffect.DimColor.RGB And &HFF0000) \ &H10000) & ", " & _
                ((behavior.ColorEffect.DimColor.RGB And &HFF00) \ &H100) & ", " & _
                (behavior.ColorEffect.DimColor.RGB And &HFF) & ")"
        Case msoAnimAfterEffectHide
            Print #fileNumber, "   After Animation: Hide"
       Case Else
            Print #fileNumber, "   After Animation: Unknown Effect"
    End Select
End if

But I cannot "get to" the ColorEffect attributes.
Thanks for listening
Charlie
